# How to Reinstall Ubuntu on Acer C7 Chromebook

Tags: system-installation, 13.04, 13.10, chromebook

I installed ChrUbuntu 13.04 and it works great. Recently, I was updating some programs when a pop-up appeared asking if I wanted to upgrade to the newest version. I didn't realize that it was still unstable and buggy. I am unsure on how to upgrade. I've been told that I need to wipe the Ubuntu partition completely, but I don't see why that is necessary.

Basically I want to remove Ubuntu 13.10 and install 13.04 on the partition where 13.10 used to be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [True Ubuntu on Chromebook ARM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm)

Comment: This feels like a relevant link to add to this page: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-chromebook#1-overview

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you yesterday, where after upgrading to Saucy, launcher bar was wonky, etc.

Since I don't use ChromeOS at all and have already voided my warranty with a RAM upgrade, I chose to short the firmware write-protect jumper and overwrote that with coreboot / seabios. Now it runs Saucy perfectly and can boot any bootable USB live CD, installer, etc. Full instructions found here: http://johnlewis.ie/pre-built-coreboot-firmware-for-chromebooks/

What I did:

- Backup files to external drive
- Download Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit .iso
- Create bootable USB stick in Chrbuntu by using `gparted` to make a 1 GB fat32 partition, and `usb-creator-gtk` to write the .iso image and boot sector
- Run `sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 0 -S 0 /dev/sda` in a terminal to make it reboot to ChromeOS
- Shut down
- Remove back cover and fold a small piece of aluminium foil to close write-protect jumper "under black plastic" in [this picture](https://a77db9aa-a-7b23c8ea-s-sites.googlegroups.com/a/chromium.org/dev/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/acer-c7-chromebook/acer-c7-bottom-guts.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7coZywPfM7_SaR1kRUS4pdQAf3xukePb1OJWyNuJ8uij7gVLk_9fkfdtNw-Uv8jaX4q3RcM9DR6jiDWgOJVjV1K_EAJTOUsIHetCg5O5MK8kYCnnWi0ef-MNZ_-3bpZf1U9hI734jkAjZeZHzPWpdHgWIN6_9l2sBaMmsEdXNfZB_bR_tPcNLdhjChwhUY1F1BPLM7UeOGbsj22TX7EyE8Od7tIu2k-Vr3gkDBYzSiw9n4EUVYBPYraDyfDfMXHt881EdrsrtjdWBbHsTSFJJzyVZN1qmwOo6sUaA9TGhwbXHufpq_rtH0byUp-EHW61ityndy7E&attredirects=0), although on my particular machine, there was no plastic shield and the jumper was exposed
- Start up and login
- `Ctrl+Alt+t` to get a crosh tab
- type `shell`
- type `sudo flashrom -r <removable media path>/stock-firmware.rom` (Important if you want to revert to ChromeOS, as apparently each Chromebook has a unique serial written in its firmware.)
- type `wget http://johnlewis.ie/coreboot-c7-04092013.rom` (Download John Lewis' firmware image)
- type `sudo flashrom -w coreboot-c7-04092013.rom`
- Shut down
- Remove aluminium foil to re-enable firmware write-protect (or coreboot won't start)
- Plug in bootable USB stick, USB mouse and start up (trackpad is not available yet)
- Hit `F10` at boot selection screen and `2` to boot from USB
- Install Ubuntu normally
- Edit `/etc/modules` and add lines:

> i2c-i801
>   i2c-dev
>   chromeos-laptop
>   cyapa
>
> Reboot and trackpad should start working

Comment: NB: Installing coreboot BIOS could brick your machine if you're not careful. I would advise reading *everything* on this page before you proceed: http://johnlewis.ie/coreboot-on-chromebooks/pre-built-firmware

Answer (score 0):

Might want to take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version) answer, it seems to address what you wish to do.

In times like this, I simply wipe everything and recreate and reinstall my partitions from scratch, just make sure you back up whatever you may need. A clean install doesn't take too long, and then you don't have to worry about things not working - or at least, things you don't already expect on a fresh install and haven't addressed before.

Comment: I found that post earlier but, it doesn't quite answer my question. How do I wipe everything? how do i recreate the partitions?

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu originally? Do what you did last time. Upon installation Ubuntu will give you a few options on how it should install, one of those involves wiping the partitions completely and recreating them itself.

Comment: Oh, I installed it using this guide http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2013/05/chrubuntu-one-script-to-rule-them-all_31.html, since it downloads and installs it directly i didnt know it would be able to remove or modify anything.  ill try and let you know how it goes, Thanks!