# Uninstalling Ubuntu on Chromebook

Tags: system-installation, uninstall, chromebook, reinstall

Look, this whole Ubuntu thing has turned out to be a disaster catastrophic. It’s all buggered up. I’m looking to uninstall it. It’s currently on my Chromebook C720, and **keep in mind that my hard drive is now partitioned** (`ctr + l` for linux `ctr + d` for Chrome). What steps do I need to take to uninstall Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest solution would be to backup data and reinstall, your might also find these answers relevant: [How to Reinstall Ubuntu on Acer C7 Chromebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360737/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-on-acer-c7-chromebook)